# A better way to convert `File[]` to `List<String>`

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to list all folders in sdcard via ListAdapter. But I'm getting runtime exceptions @ `item.add(file.getName() + "/");`. Is there a better way to convert `File[]` to `List<String>`?

```
private List <String>        item    = null;

String extState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (!extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    ....
} else {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    FileFilter filterDirectoriesOnly = new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isDirectory();
        }
    };
    File[] sdDirectories = sd.listFiles(filterDirectoriesOnly);
    for (int i = 0; i < sdDirectories.length; i++) {
        File file = sdDirectories[i];
        item.add(file.getName() + "/");
    }
    ArrayAdapter <String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter <String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a little shorter by using an enhanced for loop:

```
File[] sdDirectories = sd.listFiles(filterDirectoriesOnly);
for (File file : sdDirectories)
{
    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
}
```

There's a [method to get file names directly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29), but they won't have your trailing `/`, and you have to be able to filter by file name:

```
String[] fileNames = sd.list(fileNameFilter);
List<String> fileNamesList = Arrays.asList(fileNames);
```

Comment: @BinoyBabu - You're right, that will only work if you can filter by file name :\

Comment: @BinoyBabu - Unfortunately, you're filtering by file type, which you can't do with a FileNameFilter. I think the enchanced for loop version is the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting runtime Exception bacause

> private List item = null;

is never initialised..

so first initialise then add..

What ever you are doing seems just right.. except that initialization..

Comment: You are right but you are not answering the OP Answer.. A better way to convert `File[]` to `List<String>`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your list (hence the Exception). But apart from that, looks pretty much alright to me. I mean, it is atleast what I would do. The only thing I would recommend here is that you don't re-instantiate the variables `File sd` and `FileFilter filterdirectoriesOnly` within the function, because I assume you would be calling it again and again as the user clicks on a directory and then loads results for a new directory. So the two objects I mentioned are the same but being re-initialised every time you make a call. You could just move it outside.